# EARLIER IN A MEASURE?

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

**I was working on the conversion of a sql request into a dax one. The request is the following :**

```
> ;WITH cte
> AS
> (
>        SELECT uc.idU_Email
>               ,uc.id_Type
>               ,uc.dRecueil
>               ,valeur
>               ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY idU_Email,id_Type ORDER BY dRecueil DESC, valeur ASC) AS rang
>        FROM   vUE uc 
>        WHERE uc.Id_Type=1  AND uc.dRecueil<=DATE(02/04/2018) 
> )                   
> SELECT COUNT(idU_Email)
>     FROM   cte
>     WHERE  rang = 1 
>     and valeur = 0
```

If i understood well, the equivalent of the rownumber function in sql is the RANKX Function in DAX. So basically, to achieve the conversion i created a new calculated column.

To resume it, it makes a ranking on every partition of idU_Email (the primary key) and an other partition (inside the first one) for each id_Type, ordered it by dRecueil (a date) and then by valeur (a bit), and is filtered by a condition on the date (dRecueil). 
Thus, I've achieved to partition as I wanted to do and to apply a date filter with the following expression :

```
> RANK_OnDate2 = IF(vUE[dRecueil] <= DATE(02/04/2018) 
>             ;RANKX(FILTER(vUE; vUE[idU_Email] = EARLIER(vUE[idU_Email]) && vUE[dRecueil] <= DATE(02/04/2018)  && vUE[id_Type] = EARLIER(vUE[id_Type]))
>                 ;RANKX(ALL(vUE); vUE[dRecueil]; ;ASC) 
>                 +
>                 DIVIDE(
>                     RANKX(ALL(vUE); vUE[valeur]; ; DESC; Skip)
>                     ;COUNTROWS(ALL(vUE)) + 1
>                 )
>             )
>         )
```

And finally, I count in a measure the distinct Idu_Email where RANK_OnDate2 = 1 and valeur =0, so that i get the same result than for my sql request.

The problem is that I would like it to filter dynamically with a date saved in a measure (used as a slicer)... 
Thus, i understand that column can't be filtered dynamically, and that i should do the equivalent of my sql request directly in a measure.

I tried to do directly the distinct count in a measure but I can't solve the different issues encountered...

Particularly, i haven't achieved to used the function earlier in a measure (or to find something that would do the same)....

The measure should globally look like something like that :

```
TESTOptout2 = IF(vUE[dRecueil] <= My_Measures[datefilter]
                ;CALCULATE(
                    DISTINCTCOUNT(vUE[idU_Email])
                    ;RANKX(FILTER(vUE; vUE[idU_Email] = EARLIER(vUE[idU_Email]) && vUE[dRecueil] <= My_Measures[datefilter] && vUE[id_Type] = EARLIER(vUE[id_Type]))
                        ;RANKX(ALL(vUE); vUE[dRecueil]; ;ASC) 
                        +
                        DIVIDE(
                            RANKX(ALL(vUE); vUE[valeur]; ; DESC; Skip)
                            ;COUNTROWS(ALL(vUE)) + 1
                            )
                        ) = 1
                    ;vUE[valeur]=0
                )
            )
```

**Example** : 
If we took a dataset like this one :

```
Table : vUE 

idU     ||id_Type   ||valeur    ||dRecueil

1       ||1         ||1         ||02/04/2018
1       ||1         ||0         ||03/04/2018
1       ||1         ||1         ||01/04/2018
1       ||1         ||1         ||03/04/2018
1       ||2         ||1         ||01/04/2018
2       ||1         ||1         ||01/04/2018
2       ||3         ||1         ||02/04/2018
3       ||2         ||1         ||01/04/2018
4       ||1         ||1         ||01/04/2018
4       ||1         ||1         ||03/04/2018
5       ||1         ||1         ||03/04/2018
```

The request will first order the data like this :

```
idU     ||id_Type   ||valeur    ||dRecueil

1       ||1         ||0         ||03/04/2018
1       ||1         ||1         ||03/04/2018
1       ||1         ||1         ||02/04/2018
1       ||1         ||1         ||01/04/2018

1       ||2         ||1         ||01/04/2018


2       ||1         ||1         ||01/04/2018

2       ||3         ||1         ||02/04/2018


3       ||2         ||1         ||01/04/2018


4       ||1         ||1         ||03/04/2018
4       ||1         ||1         ||01/04/2018


5       ||1         ||1         ||03/04/2018
```

Then group by according to the date condition (on dRecueil) and the Id_Type, so if we keep the conditions of the sql request i would returned :

```
idU     ||id_Type   ||valeur    ||dRecueil

1       ||1         ||1         ||02/04/2018

2       ||1         ||0         ||01/04/2018

4       ||1         ||0         ||01/04/2018

5       ||1         ||1         ||03/04/2018
```

And the final step of the request would be to count only where valeur= 0, so 
the request would have returned 2.

But I really have to use that only in a measure because i want my date condition to be modified dynamically with a slicer

**Have you got some ideas ?
Thanks by advance !**

Comment: `EARLIER` is usually used only for calculated columns. In a measure, you typically need to use aggregate functions like `VALUES` or `MAX` instead. If you provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then I probably help further. Otherwise, this is too difficult to do answer blindly.

Comment: Hi @AlexisOlson, basically i just want the same result than the sql request would returned.
I just added an example of a data set and the result i would like to display.
Tell me if that's clearer or if that's remain very confused !